# Does MFRC522 module read all 13.56 MHz RFID tags?

Tags: arduino-uno, arduino-nano, spi, rfid, uart

**Hello everyone. Does MFRC522 module read all 13.56 MHz RFID tags?
Or there are different types of the 13.56 MHz tags that the MFRC522 module reads only one type of them?**

Comment: The second sentence of the datasheet: `The MFRC522 supports all variants of the MIFARE Mini, MIFARE 1K,
MIFARE 4K, MIFARE Ultralight, MIFARE DESFire EV1 and MIFARE Plus RF
identification protocols.`

Comment: Thanks a lot...